# multiprocessing error in Pandas

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I tried to use multiprocessing in pandas:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
def applyParallel(DF, func, data):
    with Pool(cpu_count()) as p:
        ret_list = p.map(func, [(DF, group) for name, group in data])
    return pd.concat(ret_list, axis  = 1)

def apply_row_foo(input_df, data_group):
    dfn = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in data_group['name']:
        dfn['result_' + str(i)] = input_df['student'].apply(lambda x : myfunction(x, i))
    return dfn

if __name__ == '__main__':
    z = applyParallel(df.groupby(df.index % 4), apply_row_foo, DATA)

TypeError: apply_row_foo() missing 1 required positional argument: data_group
```

How to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined `apply_row_foo` to take two parameters but you are actually calling it with those two arguments in a single tuple. One way to fix this would be to have `apply_row_foo` accept the tuple parameter:

```
def apply_row_foo(params):
    input_df, data_group = params
```

Answer (score 0):

apply_row_foo() is a function where you are passing two arguments and you are not passing them while calling it function. Just give the required arguments to the function in order of what is given or provide something like

function(arg1=val1, arg2=val2)